# Why do my discrete plots fail?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to make a discrete plot of this function:

```
y[k] = ( 0.2 * sin(k) )/k.
```

But when I evaluated this:

```
DiscretePlot[(0.2 * sin (x))/x, {x, -9.4, 9.4}]
```

I get a infinite and indeterminate expression warning.

Ok, I know that, but I still want to plot it with this range(-9.4, 9.4). So I tried this:

```
DiscretePlot[(0.2 * sin (x))/x, {x, 0.1, 9.4}]
```

But it plots nothing. What should I do?

Comment: Write `DiscretePlot[0.2*Sin[x]/x, {x, -9.4, 9.4}]` - Square brackets !

Comment: Didn't you read anything about the basic syntax of *Mathematica*? (1) arguments of all functions are enclosed in square-brackets `[ ]`, not parentheses; names of built-in functions begin with an upper-case letter (e.g., `Sin` and not `sin`); (3) a function definition normally takes the form `func[arg1_, arg2_, ...] := ....`.

Comment: You might want to use `Sinc[]` here.

Comment: And `Sin` on `Sinc` (not `sin` or `sinc`)!  And why do you want `DiscretePlot` rather than `Plot`?

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[.2 Sin[x]/x, {x, -9.4, 9.4}]
```

[image]

or

```
ListPlot[Table[.2 Sin[x]/x, {x, -9.4, 9.4}]]
```

[image]

or

```
DiscretePlot[.2 Sin[x]/x, {x, -9.4, 9.4, 1}]
```

[image]